# Is it possible to run multiple SPFx local workbenches for multiple user accounts in a single Azure VM?

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, spfx-webparts, 2019, workbench

Is it possible to serve multiple local workbenches for a single solution in one VM with multiple user accounts?

We are working on an SPFx development solution using SharePoint 2019, using one VM with multiple user accounts. We need to simultaneously run two instances of gulp serve of the same SPFx solution for the user accounts.

However, when we run the same configuration of `serve.json` in one user, it returns warning message saying 'ports are in use', since the other user uses the same configuration.

How do we simultaneously serve multiple instances? How to configure additional ports?

We are using the following versions:

- SharePoint: 2019
- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.10.0
- gulp-cli@2.3.0
- yo@3.1.1